# Inconsistent error when moving worksheet

Tags: vba, excel

The code below is a function to move a worksheet in a workbook. It gets called from a userform that contains a listbox that lists the worksheets in the workbook. The input is an integer that gives the direction which to move the sheet. Left/right in workbook is up/down in the userform listbox, and the userform has up and down buttons that calls the function with different input (+1 for moving right and -2 for moving left).

This function sometimes gives the error Method 'Move' if object '_Worksheeet' failed, but not consistently. Mostly the error comes when moving a sheet a second time, so that I am not able to move a sheet more than once. Once the error occurs I am not able to move the sheet again. I can, however, select a different sheet and move this once before the same thing occurs.

If I implement a message box in the error handling, the behaviour changes. After closing the message box upon error, I can proceeed to move the same sheet again after an error. With a message box I can therefore move a sheet as many times as I want, but it only moves on every other button press. I guess the message box breaks code execution, which for some reason makes the function work again even one the same sheet that gave the error. I have tried replacing the message box with a delay or a selfclosing infobox but this does not give the same result.

To further complicate matters, sometimes when I open the userform application, the move buttons work perfectly without any error. I think this happens when the worksheet is already open before the application is opened.

It all seems very inconsistent, and beyond my knowledge. Any help or suggestions much appreciated.

```
Function FlyttMåling(Retning As Integer) As Boolean

    Application.EnableEvents = False
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False

    'code to reference the correct workbook based on outside parameters
    Dim wb As Workbook, ws As Worksheet
    FlyttMåling = True
    If Hovedvindu.LuftlydKnapp.Value = True Then
        Set wb = ÅpneBok(1)
    ElseIf Hovedvindu.TrinnlydKnapp.Value = True Then
        Set wb = ÅpneBok(2)
    End If

    'sets variable to the index of sheet to be moved, chosen from list in userform
    Dim nummer As Integer
    Set ws = wb.Sheets(1)
    If Hovedvindu.MålingerFrame.Liste.ListIndex < 0 Then
        Exit Function
    Else
        Set ws = wb.Sheets(Hovedvindu.MålingerFrame.Liste.Value)
    End If
    nummer = ws.Index

    'exit function if trying to move first sheet to the left or last sheet to the right
    If (Retning = 1 And nummer = wb.Sheets.count) Or (Retning = -2 And nummer = 2) Then
        Exit Function
    End If

    'code that moves worksheet
    ws.Activate
    On Error GoTo errHandler:
errResume:
    ws.Move after:=wb.Sheets(nummer + Retning)   'THIS LINE CAUSES ERROR
    On Error GoTo 0
    Call oppdaterListe

    'reselect the moved worksheet in the userform list
    For i = 0 To Hovedvindu.MålingerFrame.Liste.ListCount - 1
        If ws.Name = Hovedvindu.MålingerFrame.Liste.List(i) Then
            Hovedvindu.MålingerFrame.Liste.Selected(i) = True
            Exit For
        End If
    Next i

    Application.EnableEvents = True
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    Exit Function

    'error handling just sets the return to false to notify failure to move sheet
errHandler:
    FlyttMåling = False

End Function
```

Comment: Have you verified that the move is actually valid? Your code says "move the worksheet so that it is located after the worksheet with index (nummer + Retning)" -- are you sure there exists a worksheet with this particular index in the cases where you do get an error? It also looks like your "exit function" check won't fire properly because the conditions are flipped.

Comment: The move should be valid. The index is selected from the userform list which is populated by the workbook sheets. I have also verified by printing a message box which shows the workbook name, index and name of the sheet to be moved, the index sheet should move to etc to manually verify that it tries to move the correct sheet.

Comment: The exit check should be correct. If 'retning' = 1 the sheet should move right (after index+1). This should not happen if the sheet is already the last (=sheet.count). If 'retning' = -2 the sheet should move left. This should not happen if the sheet index = 2 (Sheet nr 2 is the first data sheet, and the first in the userform list. Sheet nr 1 is always a dummy sheet which is not shown in the userform list, and should never be moved)

Comment: Ok, I see your "exit function" logic better now. I guess that *should* also solve any secondary worksheet reference problems... but just to be sure, can you verify that the worksheet you are referencing in the move is valid as well? I mean `wb.Sheets(nummer + Retning)`. You can do this by adding a simple `Debug.Print wb.Sheets(nummer + Retning).Name` (which will error out if the reference is invalid.

Comment: I have just verified as you suggested that both the sheet to be moved and the sheet it should be placed after are valid when the error occurs.

Comment: Try changing it from `Function` to `Sub`. Functions are ordinarily not allowed to make worksheet changes, so the error might be related to that.

Comment: This unfortunately does not resolve the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Found a workaround for this problmem. Changing the wb.move to a wb.copy, and then deleting the old sheet and renaming the copy to the name of the original sheet makes this code work as intended.